# Odd nature of sine function. (Taylor series)

Tags: taylor-expansion

Although, this might be silly question. I am just wondering what happens to the odd nature of $\sin \theta$ when I expand it about some   $ \pi/4 $. There are terms with even powers appearing as well. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The even terms appear because $\sin \theta$ isn't odd about the point $\pi/4$. That is, $\sin(\theta-\pi/4)$ isn't odd. In fact, it's neither even nor odd. If you do an expansion about the point $\pi/2$, you will only see even terms.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Oddness and evenness that we generally consider for a function is therefore only about zero (or about its periodic point).